# How to send data to custom host

Tags: javascript

I made a script to send POST data to specific endpoint but on click it is sending the request to my localhost instead of that i want it to send it to somesite.com/endpoint.

My code:

```
<html>
<body>
<script>
function submitForm(oFormElement)
{
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("POST", '/asset/6431/comments/add', true);

//Send the proper header information along with the request
xhr.setRequestHeader("X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest");

xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {//Call a function when the state changes.
    if(this.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE && this.status == 200) {
        // Request finished. Do processing here.
    }
}
xhr.send("message=dd");
}
</script>
<form method="post"  onsubmit="return submitForm(this);">   
<input type="submit"></input>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

It is sending request to localhost/asset/6431/comments/add

Please help:

Comment: its doing that because thats where your sending it `xhr.open("POST", '/asset/6431/comments/add', true);` it can only end locally as it doesn't have a domain set infront of the path

Comment: @Parody how to do so? I'm new to programming. I added xhr.open("POST", 'site.com/asset/6431/comments/add', true); 


but still its sending localhost

Comment: if you want to send to `somesite.com/` you need to assign `somesite.com/` not just the path `'/asset/6431/comments/add'` so it would be `somesite.com/asset/6431/comments/add'`

Answer (score 0):

In your code you are mentioned the URL as a relative path. So usually it will look for the server, to make the URL full path. I think you tried this code in your local, so it's adding localhost in-front. And if you tried in any server host, it will show the server/domian name there. If you want to send the request to some particular end point, you have to mention it clearly in the url/path parameter. In your case it should be like below.

```js
xhr.open("POST", 'https://www.somesite.com/asset/6431/comments/add', true);
```

)